# Phonegap 3.3 inapp browser doesn't show close button in ios 7

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, inappbrowser

I have a phonegap app with an in-app browser with loads a remote webpage..e.g www.google.com.

However in iOS 7, the close button doesn't appear despite all the correct settings.

Strangely it works in iOS 6.

Other answers on stack overflow suggest the inapp browser is not being run. How do I check this? How do I make sure the inapp browser is called?

Comment: My mistake, this seems to have been fixed in p.g 3.3 - something in my html caused a problem.. when i reverted to an older version of my web app everything worked fine.